# Sniff packets forwarded by ProxyCap

Tags: sockets, proxy, scapy, socks, sniffing

I'm communicating with a socket server, using TOR, through a SOCKS5 proxy configured with ProxyCap (Hostname 127.0.0.1, port 9150).

My aim is to sniff the packets sent by the socket server. I tried to use Scapy sniff function but I only get packets encrypted by TOR. Is is possible to sniff the packets that ProxyCap forwards to my client ?

To summarize :

Socket server <-> TOR <-> ProxyCap <-> Client.

I need to get the packets corresponding to the last <->.

Comment: Where are you running your sniffing code? If on ProxyCap, you can capture on the egress interface to your Client. If you can run it on your Client, I don't think there is a problem?

Comment: I forgot to mention that TOR, ProxyCap, the Client and Scapy are running on the same computer.